# mysql query fails at filtering data?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

here is my `user_crime_details` table:

[image]

When I try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`user_crime_details`)
WHERE  `group_id` =  '1'
AND  `insert_date` = CURDATE( ) 
OR  `last_update_date` = CURDATE( ) 
ORDER BY  `id` DESC
```

This is always the result:

[image]

You can see the results are wrong because the group_id's not equal to 1 were also selected.
Is there something wrong with my query? Pls help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to group the condition by adding parenthesis on the `OR` part.

```
WHERE  group_id =  1  AND  
       (insert_date = CURDATE() OR  last_update_date = CURDATE())
```

and which is the same as

```
WHERE  group_id =  1 AND CURDATE() IN (insert_date, last_update_date)
```

PS: the backticks around the columns are *optional* since the names are not on the list of reserved keywords in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

The result isnt wrong, because the condition after the or is for every row TRUE (last_update_date = CURDATE())

I think you wanted this query?:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`user_crime_details`)
WHERE
   `group_id` =  '1'
AND 
  (
     `insert_date` = CURDATE( ) 
      OR  `last_update_date` = CURDATE( ) 
  )
ORDER BY  `id` DESC
```